# 22.04 Server automatically reboots after sudo shutdown -P now or with sudo power off instruction

Tags: server, 22.04, shutdown, wakeonlan

I am currently using 22.04 Server on a NUC 10i7FN. It was working for months without issues.
Since the last update neither power off or shutdown commands are working as expected.
The system shut downs and restarts immediately, it is acting as if  I've requested a reboot instead.

Does someone have an idea?

This tiny server is supposed to be recycled into spare (in case of crash) for a couple of days or weeks as we are running disaster recovery plan exercises between site.
It should wait powered off till someone requires the internal network services to be recovered from a safe snapshot.

I've tried to deactivate WOL: no effect, it' s rebooting again and again. The only fix: unplugging the power cord.

Comment: You claim this started "*since last update*". Did you review your apt logs in /var/log/apt to see what that update consisted of?

Comment: On this server  previous update was done many months ago, 

3 to 4 times a year, I use to run : 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo rclone selfupdate

so it was a hugh upgrade, and before it, I could power it off with CMDLine rather than powercord.

Comment: /var/loog/apt/history contents: hundreds of lib and modules modified: 
Start-Date: 2022-10-01  21:34:47
Commandline: apt-get upgrade

Comment: I have a 6th gen Intel NUC with Ubuntu 22.04 desktop. It does the same thing. I can shut down right after it comes back up. That's is it works the second time.

Comment: shutdown, poweroff command are basics of basics command! WTF with this system?
it was working fine with 18.04, 20.04.
The worst about this issue: the GUI command of our standard window manager is working fine, it is doing the job, the NUC  is powerded off, and it DOESN'T RESTART BY ITSELF!

Other issue, there is no way to customize TIMEOUT DELAY in GRUB 2.06 (the paramareter into /etc/default/grub (GRUB_TIMEOUT=5)

Comment: I've never had any of my Windows machines unable to power down properly, ever. Now all of the sudden I install Ubuntu Server on my Intel  NUCs and none of them can shut themselves off! This is absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: sometime they can, sometime they can't this is what we can call an Heisenberg poweroff feature, NUCs are currently Quantic computers. LOL!

Can you also set Grub TIMEOUT DELAY to something different of the default value (30 sec). and this "custom" value become effective when you reboot?
On my side last version of Grub is a totalitarian boot loader. No way to reduce from 30 to something else (nor to increase).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the similar issue setting `acpi=noirq` in the grub file:

•   Open the terminal.

•   Type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and press Enter. This will open the grub configuration file in a text editor.

•   Find the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `acpi=noirq` to the end of the quoted text. For example, it might look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=noirq".
```

•   Save the file and exit the text editor.

•   Update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

•   Reboot your system:

```
sudo reboot
```