# POWER OFF COMMAND DOES NOT WORK on 22.04

Tags: 22.04, power-management, shutdown

2 issues impacting basic Linux features:

First issue:
Since I've upgraded to 22.04 my 2 NUCs, (from 18.04 and 20.04) both of them are unable to be powered-off by the command line.
Neither the command

```
sudo poweroff
```

nor the command

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

are doing the job. The NUC are always rebooting instead.
The only 2 ways to switch them off is

1. unplug the powercord
2. USE the windows manager GUI command (upper button on the right corner of Standard 22.04 windows manager.

2nd Issue:
`GRUB_TIMEOUT` delay parameter placed into `/etc/default/grub` does not have any effect (Grub 2.06)!

As these 2 NUC should host network services and virtualization, they are not supposed to get windows manager but just a ssh services. Please can you help me to find a fix.
Power off and shutdown are basics for many decades!

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398) may help you with graphics via ssh.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again and again. [22.04 Server automatically reboots after sudo shutdown -P now or with sudo power off instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433700/22-04-server-automatically-reboots-after-sudo-shutdown-p-now-or-with-sudo-power)

Comment: Check your UEFI settings.  Power State set to Always-on will automatically power-on if a usb adapter is connected. When changing grub.cfg does not take effect, maybe grub is using some other root than you expect -- could you have some other root which really controls the grub menu?

Answer (score 0):

Keep calm :)

> shutdown -h now

This will effectively halt your system.

As for the Grub timeout, after you have edited/etc/default/grub

> sudo update-grub

Is required to notify the bootloader about your changes.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

history | grep grub reports:

```
1797  sudo vi /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub
1821  sudo vi /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub
```

shutdown -h now is not running better than poweroff cmdline, my parameters are:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
GRUB_GFXMODE=3840x2160x32,3840x2160x24,3840x2160,1920x1080x32,1920x1080x24,1920x1080x16,1920x1080,1280x1024,1024x768x32,1024x768x24,1024x768x16,1024x768,800x600,640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: This is not an answer.   You should place such additional information into your original posting.